# Is it possible to increase compatibility of AngularJS to IE6?

Tags: angularjs, compatibility

By using polyfills is it possible to develop web apps with AngularJS for IE6 ? If so what are some of the polyfills that I would require ?

Comment: IE6.. ? which planet are you from... ? :)

Comment: @VinayK I have seen people still using XP with IE6. Just trying to achieve maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this is simply not possible.

Why would you want to support IE6? IE6 has less than 1.1% usage worldwide. It would be an overkill.

[Angular supports IE9+.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie)

You could display a 'please upgrade your browser' type message for IE8 and below.

Comment: Hmm I see. Just trying to make my code as portable as possible. Would be great if angularJS was as compatible as jQuery.

Comment: @Heidi jQuery supports IE9+.

Comment: jQuery supports all browsers right from IE6. I was wondering if AngularJS can be made as compatible as that using polyfills.

Comment: I'm afraid not, the latest version of jQuery supports IE9+ http://jquery.com/browser-support/